# Why Collections.min(Arrays.asList(new Base(), new Base())) gives a strange compile error (Eclipse)?

Tags: java, eclipse, collections, compiler-errors

Why for class Base I get a strange compile error (Eclipse):

```
 Collections.min(Arrays.asList(new Base(), new Base()));
```

fails with compile error:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<Base> to Collection<? extends T>
    - The method min(Collection<? extends T>) in the type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (List<Base>)
```

P.S. I understand that class Base shall be Comparable, but the compiler complains not about that...   min expects Collection as its argument, and Arrays.asList returns List, List is a Collection.

The error above is gone if I make class Base implement Comparable, but anyway the error is strange.

Comment: There's no particular specification for compiler error messages, so Eclipse can more or less say whatever it wants. Aside from the fact that it correctly says that the `min` method isn't applicable (not that it's even required to say that much), we can only guess about why it says one thing over another. [Javac says something else.](https://ideone.com/gjCU7Y)

Answer (score 3):

The reason that it compiles after having `Base` implement `Comparable` is because of `Collections#min`'s signature:

```
public static <T extends Object & Comparable<? super T>> T min(Collection<? extends T> coll)
```

You can see that `T` must be `Comparable` and will not compile otherwise.

Another solution is to pass an explicit `Comparator` to the overloaded method:

```
public static <T> T min(Collection<? extends T> coll, Comparator<? super T> comp)
```